# Django 2.2. Вместо моего шаблона django использует стандартный из админки

Tags: python, django

В django создал приложение **authapp**. Зарегистрировал его в settings и добавил в основной **urls.py**:
`path('authapp/', include('authapp.urls', namespace='authapp')),`
В **authapp/urls.py** добавил:

```
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

path('password_change/', auth_views.PasswordChangeView.as_view(success_url=reverse_lazy('authapp:password_change_done')), name='password_change'),
path('password_change/done/', auth_views.PasswordChangeDoneView.as_view(), name='password_change_done'),
```

Добавил свои шаблоны в **authapp/templates/registration**:
- password_change_form.html
- password_change_done.html
Но при переходе по `http://127.0.0.1:8000/authapp/password_change/` попадаю на форму в админке django, а не в мою форму...
Что делаю не так?

Comment: Покажите полностью свой `urls.py` (корневой)

Comment: @Александр
`from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('mainapp.urls', namespace='main')),
    path('authapp/', include('authapp.urls', namespace='authapp')),
]`

Comment: Так и не могу починить...

Comment: Внутри `PasswordChangeDoneView` нет редиректа?

Comment: Может, у вас login_required где-то стоит на эту вьюху с автопереадресацией?

Comment: @Александр, я же `PasswordChangeDoneView` импортирую из `django.contrib.auth`, как собственно и `PasswordChangeView`. Вьюха получается стандартная. Но шаблон по задумке должен браться мой из папки `templates` приложения (делаю по книге "Django 2 by Example"). А когда я перехожу по `/authapp/password_change/`, то попадаю на стандартный шаблон.

Comment: понял. попробуйте в `PasswordChangeView.as_view` указать template_name в качестве параметра: `PasswordChangeView.as_view(template_name="ваш_password_change.html")`

Comment: Либо переставить в installed_apps вашего settings.py `"admin"` после `"authapp"`. Но лучше тот, что выше, вариант, тк этот не уверен, что сработает

Comment: @Александр, спасибо огромное! Сработал как раз **второй** вариант.
Первый не смог запустить. Делал вот так:
`path('password_change/',
     auth_views.PasswordChangeView.as_view(
         success_url=reverse_lazy('authapp:password_change_done'),
         template_name='registration/password_change_form.html'
     ),
     name='password_change'),`

Comment: какая ошибка при первом варианте? Не найден шаблон?

Comment: @Александр, да, видимо. Просто молча переходит на шаблон по умолчанию.